# CoreOSのコンテナが定期的に止まってしまう。

Tags: docker, coreos

CoreOSのDockerで常駐型のコンテナを幾つか動かしているのですが、1、2週間ごとにすべてのコンテナが勝手に止まってしまいます。

OSはStableチャンネルを使用していて、自動アップデートは行うように設定しています。SSHで接続して`docker ps`を実行すると止まっていたすべてのコンテナが動き出します。

勝手にコンテナが止まらないようにするにはどうすればよいのでしょうか。